# How to remove pagestack into windows phone 7.?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have app which contain 5 page, end last page will be called signout so once I clicked to the signout it will remove all the pagestack and start to navigate from the page 1.

eg: page-1 MainMenu

page-2 list of Items.

page-3 which Common Sharing Options(of Facebook and twiter)

page-4 Point showing list which is highest earned point.

page-5 sign-out.

Once I clicked on Sign-out it will goes to Login Page. and Once it logged In it will redirect to me page -5.

so my question is I want to redirect to the page 2. so how I can do this.

I had tried

> ```
>         foreach (var journalEntry in ((PhoneApplicationFrame)Application.Current.RootVisual).BackStack)
>         {
>             ((PhoneApplicationFrame)Application.Current.RootVisual).RemoveBackEntry();
> ```

```
        }
```

but it will not resolved my problem.

Thank you..!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be interested in reading the following "Solving Circular Navigation in Windows Phone Silverlight Applications" :-

http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2010/12/13/solving-circular-navigation-in-windows-phone-silverlight-applications.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can remove entries from the [BackStack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.navigationservice.backstack%28v=vs.92%29) using the [`NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.navigationservice.removebackentry%28v=vs.92%29) method

Comment: Thank you @Rowland Shaw I am using this code but still problem is not resolved.                                                 foreach (var journalEntry in ((PhoneApplicationFrame)Application.Current.RootVisual).BackStack) { ((PhoneApplicationFrame)Application.Current.RootVisual).RemoveBackEntry(); break; }

Comment: You don't want to remove all the backstack entries - just the ones that relate to the "logged in" states

Comment: I am sorry but I had added into foreach loop that time it will give me error so I have manually added 4 times foeareach and breack it for the time being.

Answer (score 1):

I created this method for removing multiple pages ('tasks') from the page stack.

```
/// <summary>
        /// Decreases the back stack entry count, leaving the amount of items on the stack equilivent to the <param name="leaveAmount">leaveAmount</param>.
        /// </summary>
        /// <exception cref="NotSupportedException">A value less than 0 is provided</exception>
        /// <param name="leaveAmount">The leave amount.</param>
        /// <param name="whenFinished"> </param>
        public static void DecreaseBackStackEntryCount(int leaveAmount, Action whenFinished = null)
        {
            if (leaveAmount < 0)
            {
                throw new NotSupportedException("cannot remove every item on stack");
            }
            Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                                                          {
                                                              try
                                                              {
                                                                  while (((PhoneApplicationFrame)Application.Current.RootVisual).BackStack.Count() > leaveAmount)
                                                                  {
                                                                      try
                                                                      {
                                                                          ((PhoneApplicationFrame) Application.Current.RootVisual).RemoveBackEntry();
                                                                      }
                                                                      catch (InvalidOperationException)
                                                                      {
                                                                          return;
                                                                      }
                                                                  }

                                                              }
                                                              catch
                                                              {
                                                              }
                                                              finally
                                                              {
                                                                  if (whenFinished != null)
                                                                  {
                                                                        whenFinished.Invoke();
                                                                  }
                                                              }
                                                          });
        }
```

on page 5, you'd use it like: (I THINK you're trying to go back to the main menu after signout.. if not, read the method signature)

```
DecreaseBackstackEntryCount(1,() => NavigationService.GoBack());
```

Answer (score 1):

Part of your issue may be that you are modifying the collection in your `foreach` loop and that's not going to work.

Here is a [SO question that gives you some options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232485/going-through-a-foreach-when-it-can-get-modified) for that in general situation. The gist is to use a for loop going backwards or to call `.ToArray()` or `.ToList()` and do your `foreach` on those separate collections.

However what I would do in this situation would be:

```
while (NavigationService.CanGoBack)
{
  NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();
}
```